# Single SSL certificate in a Load Balancing architecture

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I am getting into load balancing and how security with SSL certificates can be integrated with a load balancer.

Let's say that I want to expose several copies of the same RESTful web service over Amazon Elastic Load Balancer. All should be fine and smooth up until now. However, security has not yet been taken into consideration.

Now, let's say that we want the communication to be secured with an SSL certificate, so we go ahead and buy a certificate. We will have several IP addresses which are all exposing the same RESTful server with the load balancer. These IP addresses will all get mapped to the same domain name (https://thedomain.com). This way, the clients always connect to the same domain. It is then up to the load balancer to redirect to the web service which is getting the least traffic.

The main question is, is it possible for such an architecture with a single SSL certificate? As if this is so, it would be possible to extend the amount of services dynamically without having to change the security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is then up to the load balancer to redirect to the web service which is getting the least traffic.

AFAIK, the ELB supports only RoundRobin and Stick sessions. So what you said above will not happen.

> is it possible for such an architecture with a single SSL certificate?

You can install the SSL certificate on the ELB and let it do the SSL termination. The traffic between ELB and your Web Nodes will be un-encrypted then. You should explore AWS VPC where you can have a public facing ELB and your Web Nodes will be within Private subnet.

Also, ELB supports TCP load balancing. In this case, you install the Certificate on the Web Nodes and ELB will accept traffic on port 443 from internet and will simply forward it to port 443 on web nodes wherein web nodes have to do SSL encryption/decryption.

Hope this helps.

Comment: AWS VPC looks like an optimal solution for such a scenario and I will definitely look more into it. Thanks for the input.